# How to update values in a hash within an array?

Tags: ruby

Edit**
 arr = [{"tomato"=>2}, {"banana"=>3}, {"milk"=>1}, {"egg"=>1}, {"cooking foil"=>1}, {"apple"=>4}, {"apple =>6}]

How to change value`{"apple" => 10}`?

How to define function e.g.`add` to update value when same key was added?
e.g.

```
arr.add{"banana" =>7}
=>
[{"tomato"=>2}, {"banana"=>10}, {"milk"=>"1 gallon"}, {"egg"=>"1 cart"}, {"cooking foil"=>1}, {"apple"=>10}]
```

Comment: While this would works for integer values, how would you "add" string values, e.g. `"milk"`?

Comment: While it is certainly possible to work with your data structures, it will always be slow and full of special cases (e.g how to deal with duplicate values). You should strongly consider having only a single hash with multiple keys instead of your array-with-one-element-hashes. That way, you have fast access and a well-understood interface and semantics.

Comment: I expect the downvotes are from readers who did not understand your question. If my interpretation of the question is correct (see my answer), that's too bad, as it deals with a task that must arise fairly often, yet I've not seen a question quite like this one previously.  You should do an edit to clarify. You owe it to readers, including those who will come across your question in future. As an incentive, I promise an upvote for a good edit.  You might want to include the word, "Edit:", so as to not confuse those who have already seen your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function that uses [detect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) to find the given key and edit it. Also add a new entry if key is not already present. Something like:

```
def add(key, val, arr)
  a = arr.detect{|a| a[key]}
  a ? a[key] = a[key] + val : arr << {key => val}
  arr
end

arr = [{"tomato"=>2}, {"banana"=>3}, {"milk"=>"1 gallon"}, {"egg"=>"1 cart"}, {"cooking foil"=>1}, {"apple"=>4}, {"apple" =>6}]

add("apple", 10, arr)
# => [{"tomato"=>2}, {"banana"=>3}, {"milk"=>"1 gallon"}, {"egg"=>"1 cart"}, {"cooking foil"=>1}, {"apple"=>14}, {"apple"=>6}]

add("banana", 6, arr)
# => [{"tomato"=>2}, {"banana"=>9}, {"milk"=>"1 gallon"}, {"egg"=>"1 cart"}, {"cooking foil"=>1}, {"apple"=>14}, {"apple"=>6}]

add("lemon", 3, arr)
# => [{"tomato"=>2}, {"banana"=>9}, {"milk"=>"1 gallon"}, {"egg"=>"1 cart"}, {"cooking foil"=>1}, {"apple"=>14}, {"apple"=>6}, {"lemon"=>3}]
```

**Note**: as your Array has two Hashes with same keys, `detect` will change only the first occurrence. If you want to replace all the Hashes you can use [find_all](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all).

Comment: This overwrites existing values. In the OP's example, `arr.add{"banana" =>7}` changes `{"banana"=>3}` to `{"banana"=>10}`.

Comment: I didnt notice that. Thanks @Stefan. I have edited my answer. :)

Comment: Further to @Stefan's comment, it appears that `arr` is still being modified. I interpreted the question differently, but admittedly it is not clear. I've asked the OP for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed that all hashes having `"apple"` as the single key are to be replaced by a single hash `{ "apple"=>tot }`, where `tot` is the total of all values of `"apple"` in the referenced hashes. I've also assumed that `arr` is not to be altered and that the location of `{"apple"=>tot}` in the array returned is not important.

```
arr = [{"tomato"=>2}, {"banana"=>3}, {"milk"=>"1 gallon"}, {"egg"=>"1 cart"},
       {"cooking foil"=>1}, {"apple"=>4}, {"apple"=>6}]

apples = arr.select { |h| h.keys.include?("apple") }
arr - apples << { "apple"=> apples.reduce(0) { |tot,h| tot + h["apple"] } }
  #=> [{"tomato"=>2}, {"banana"=>3}, {"milk"=>"1 gallon"},
  #    {"egg"=>"1 cart"}, {"cooking foil"=>1}, {"apple"=>10}]
```

The steps:

Extract the hashes having `"apple"` as the single key (leaving `arr` unchanged):

```
apples = arr.select { |h| h.keys.include?("apple") }
  #=> [{"apple"=>4}, {"apple"=>6}]
```

Compute the total number of apples:

```
tot_apples = apples.reduce(0) { |tot,h| tot + h["apple"] }
  #=> 10
```

Select the elements of `arr` that do not have `"apple"` as a key (leaving `arr` unchanged):

```
a = arr - apples
  #=> [{"tomato"=>2}, {"banana"=>3}, {"milk"=>"1 gallon"},
  #    {"egg"=>"1 cart"}, {"cooking foil"=>1}]
```

Lastly, append `{ "apple"=>tot_apples }` to `a`:

```
a << { "apple"=>tot_apples }
  #=> [{"tomato"=>2}, {"banana"=>3}, {"milk"=>"1 gallon"},
  #    {"egg"=>"1 cart"}, {"cooking foil"=>1}, {"apple"=>10}]
```